# How do you pass value through a query string fetching from database in codeigneiter?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to pass this value in controller function, fetching id in the query string from the database:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>.'index.php?n=<?php echo p->id?>'/control/show'">show</a>
```

Comment: what is the controller and the method, you are trying to call? and what is the parameter passed?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is incorrect. Your anchor, when clicked will redirect to this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?n=3/control/show
```

CI will break error out since it does not see the controller.

You need to first create your controller like this:

```
class Control extends CI_Controller{

    public function show($id){
       // your code here
    }

}
```

Now you can use the following URL:

```
http://localhost/index.php/control/show/3
```

Or in your anchor:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/control/show/<?php echo $p->id ?>">show</a>
```